# Webmatrix Razor Summing numbers in foreach loop

Tags: razor

Inside a foreach loop i have a statement

@(var = var1 + var2 ) ;

the math occurs but the results var gets displayed on the page after each execution.  I don't want that to happen just do the math so I can display results at the bottom of the table.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the @ symbol as when you're in your for each loop, you're already in a code block.

Your code should look a little like this:

```
@foreach (var i in a)
{
    var x = i + i;
}
```